# Wordpress: Limit what html is included in the *|RSSITEM:CONTENT|* merge tag

Tags: html, wordpress, rss, mailchimp

I'm currently trying to create an email automation for my Wordpress via MailChimp that sends out the text of the email every time a new post is posted. Ideally, I would only like to include what's inside of the body tag and exclude the footer tag since it has a bunch of images & text that's irrelevant for the reader. Is there a way I can specify to exclude certain elements of the page when I use the `*|RSSITEM:CONTENT|*` merge tag?